# Why does the create_all function not create my tables?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm creating a little app with Flask and SQLAlchemy. (I'm new in Python)
Well, I want Flask-SQLAlchemy to create the tables I already defined in my code.

My project structure looks like this:

```
application
├── models
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── device.py
│   └── user.py
├── static
├── templates
├── __init__.py
├── flask_config.py
└── wsgi.py
```

The `__init__.py` inside the `models` package looks like this:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from configparser import ConfigParser


class DBHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.config = ConfigParser()
        self.configPath = r"application/config.ini"
        self.config.read(self.configPath)

        self.db_username = self.config.get("DEV", "db_username")
        self.db_password = self.config.get("DEV", "db_password")
        self.db_host = self.config.get("DEV", "db_host")
        self.db_port = self.config.get("DEV", "db_port")
        self.db_name = self.config.get("DEV", "db_name")

        self.DB_URL = 'postgresql+psycopg2://' + self.db_username + ':' + self.db_password + '@' + \
        self.db_host + ':' + self.db_port + '/' + self.db_name

        self.db = SQLAlchemy()
```

The models I defined are very simple. Here's an example of `user.py`:

```py
from application.models import DBHandler

db_handler = DBHandler()


class User(db_handler.db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db_handler.db.Column(db_handler.db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db_handler.db.Column(db_handler.db.String(200), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db_handler.db.Column(db_handler.db.String(200), unique=False, nullable=False)
```

The `__init_.py` file of the app looks like this:

```
from application.models import DBHandler
from application.flask_config import FlaskConfig

from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api


def create_app():
    application = Flask(__name__)
    flask_config_obj = FlaskConfig()
    application.config.from_object(flask_config_obj)

    db_handler_obj = DBHandler()
    db_handler_obj.db.init_app(application)

    return application
```

To create the tables I run this this code in the python console:

```
from application import create_app
import application.models
from application.models.user import User
from application.models.port import Port
from application.models.device import Device
app = create_app()
db_handler = application.models.DBHandler()
with app.app_context():
    db_handler.db.create_all()
```

The code runs without an error, but the tables are not created.
What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
Here is my Flask configuration class where I connect to the database:

```
from application.models import DBHandler


class FlaskConfig:
    def __init__(self):
        db_handler = DBHandler()
        self.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = db_handler.DB_URL
        self.SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
        self.SECRET_KEY = b'_5#y2L"F4Q8z\n\xec]/'
```

Comment: Where do you connect to the database?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add DB_URL to app config for to connect to the database:

```
db_handler_obj = DBHandler()
application.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = db_handler_obj.DB_URL
db_handler_obj.db.init_app(application)
```

Comment: Hi @Yakir Tsuberi, I already do this in my flask-configuration file. Check my edit. Thanks

Comment: Try to config with no class, like this:  `application.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = db_handler_obj.DB_URL` `application.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS '] = False` etc.

Comment: Put the configuration in the create_app function and run the create_all code but it's still not working :/